# adding a new sqlite field problem

Tags: iphone, sqlite, core-data

I've added a new field to an SQLite db table and have also added a new attribute in core data xcdatamodel. I made sure to delete the app from the iphone simulator.

the app runs fine, but isn't finding the new field. if i change the data on an existing field in SQLite and relaunch the app, the change is there. the new field is not.

anyone know what step I'm missing?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you possibly check the attribute as "Transient" in core data? Then it would not save it in the store.

> Transient properties are properties
>   that you define as part of the model,
>   but which are not saved to the
>   persistent store as part of an entity
>   instance's data. Core Data does track
>   changes you make to transient
>   properties, so they are recorded for
>   undo operations.

If the field is not visible at all, did you recreate the NSManagedObject class file for that model entity or generated accessors to your new field?

Comment: thanks for your post.

no, the Transient option is unchecked. I also made sure to recreate the NSManagedObject file w/ the new addition for that field.

one thing i noticed was that if I renamed a field that I new was working in the SQLite table the app would crash. If I renamed the new field the app would launch fine.